# Vuetify autocomplete not working when multiple prop is true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js, v-autocomplete

Im trying to make work this autocomplete with multiple prop, it works with muliple = false (default).

When I add the prop multiple to autocomplete then the dropdown doesn't show, the multiple prop works with v-select but whe i chage it to v-autocomplete is not working.

*Note: if I asign an item from the list to the v-model, it get selected but still not working as it should be*

simple code (doesn't work in my local)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-autocomplete v-model="office" :items="locations" multiple></v-autocomplete>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
            locations: ["Toronto", "New York", "San Jose", "Vancouver"],
            office: [],
        }
    }
</script>
```

this is how it looks

[image: this is how it looks]

html devtool

[image]

Vue devtool

[image]

as you can see, the v-automcplete has the items, but still not showing up, im usign the last version of vuetify (vue2)

Comment: As [written here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#asynchronous-items), you need to have `:search-input.sync="search"`. Please check the documentation and try to match the example. Since you're using `multiple` and that it's a requirement in that case.

Comment: @kissu i cant even write in the searchbox when multiple is true, I literally copied that `v-autocomplete` with multiple prop, not working :(

Comment: just to be clear: "im usign the last version of vuetify (vue2)" do you mean you're using vuetify 3 (the latest version) with vue 2?  if so, they're not compatible, vuetify 3 is only meant to be used with vue 3 and has it's own [separate documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com).  or do you mean you're using the latest vuetify version _for_ vue2, which should be vuetify v2.6.12?

Comment: @yoduh last version for vue2 - 2.6.12